# Swift, Как проверить UIButton на пустоту?

Tags: swift

Хорошего дня/вечера всем

У меня есть девять кнопок я незнаю как проверить пустые у них лейблы, например есть есть пустой лейбл у указанной кнопки то записать в него какой текст в определенном методе

Код примерно такой

```
@IBAction func clicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.someFunc()
}

func someFunc() {

  let button = self.view.viewWithTag(cell) as? UIButton

  // проверяет установлен уже символ или нет !
  if button?.currentTitle == "" {
    button?.setTitle("A", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  } else {
    print("not empty!")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Немного измените свой код, передайте в вашу функцию саму кнопку:

```
@IBAction func clicker(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.someFunc(sender)
}

func someFunc(sender : AnyObject) {
let button = sender as? UIButton
...
}
```